# YII :: CJuiDateTimePicker is not saving any data to mysql

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am using CJuiDateTimePicker in my yii application but can't save data into mysql. How can Save data into MySQL

CODE::

```
    <?php Yii::import('application.extensions.CJuiDateTimePicker.CJuiDateTimePicker');
        $this->widget('CJuiDateTimePicker',array(
            'model'=>$model, //Model object
            'attribute'=>'pp_date', //attribute name
            'language'=> '',
            'mode'=>'date', 
            'options'=>array(
                'showAnim'=>'fold',
                'changeMonth' => 'true',
                'changeYear' => 'true',
                'showOtherMonths' => 'true',
                'selectOtherMonths' => 'true',
                'showOn' => 'both',
        ),
    ));?>
```

Any Helps appreciated

Comment: Like I asked before when you asked this question, can you show your validation rules? If you haven't defined a validation rule for pp_date then you won't be able to save it. The simplest way is to add it to the 'safe' rule.

Comment: I have validation rules for pp_date. please share your code

Comment: Ok, if you've got validation rules then that excludes it as a possible cause of your problem. It would still help if you could include the code from your model and the relevant action from your controller, so we can see what might be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the Dat and Time format are mysql format

```
dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

Comment: yes got it. it will be yy-mm-dd same as mysql. Thanks for the help